# How to customize @angular-material-components/datetime-picker width?

Tags: angular-material, datetimepicker

I'm using @angular-material-components/datetime-picker library for date picker. I use hideTime to just display date picker. The simplified code is below.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker hideTime="true">
    </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The result is as follows.

[image]

How can I adjust the width of this date picker so that the highlighted area is minimal?

I tried the following style class in styles.scss, hoping to overwrite its default styling, but it does not work

```
.mat-form-field-wrapper {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 36px !important;
}
```

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `:host ::ng-deep` to allow the access of DOM elements that are not in your component's HTML and overwrite its CSS styling rule.

Note:

> Be sure to include the `:host` selector before `::ng-deep`. If the
> `::ng-deep` combinator is used without the `:host` pseudo-class selector,
> the style can bleed into other components.

> .component.css

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-wrapper {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 36px !important;
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sfchsw)

---

### References

[(deprecated) /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: thank you. it works perfect. just wondering if i can extend my question here regarding this css. how can i give two similar css for the wrapper, one is narrow and one is wide. so that i can use ngClass to decide which css class i can use. thanks

Comment: Hi, maybe you can try assign `[ngClass]` to `<mat-form-field>` element. And  in your CSS file, you add rule such as `:host ::ng-deep .your-class .mat-form-field-wrapper { /*  Styling*/ }`.Not yet tested on this but hope that this may bring you the idea to achieve your goal. Thanks.

Comment: I will make a test later in this direction. Thank you